# Xcode compile error with Firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase

I just installed the Firebase framework to Xcode (not using CocoaPods due to other unsolvable issues with that).  I followed the Firebase Alternative Setup instructions from [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/alternate-setup.html) (manually dragging the FireBase 2.5 Framework to my project).

Problem is, when I compile my app I get 27 errors:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyM8P.png)

I'm just using the sample code from the Getting Started page.

In fact, all I'm using so far is the first line, but it won't even instantiate that.  (var ref = Firebase(url:"my firebase URL here")

I'm on Xcode 7.2 and Swift 2.1.  My target is iOS 9.2 using the Simulator.

Please help!
Thanks.

PS.
I should also add that libicucore.dylib and libc++.dylib no longer appear to be available as linkable libraries that you mention to include from firebase.com/docs/ios/alternate-setup.html  So maybe this is related?  Someone mentioned libz.tbd is the one to use now? (which I'm using)

Comment: Do you  still need to include an import statement at the top of your file in order to make those types useable?

Comment: Hi Mike, yes I am using import Firebase.

Comment: the errors seem to be related to "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"?

Comment: Did you add those libraries as well: 
libicucore.dylib,
libc++.dylib,
CFNetwork.framework,
Security.framework,
SystemConfiguration.framework

Comment: I am not positive but I believe libz.tbd is the one to use now. Or possibly libs.qlite

Comment: I followed exactly steps here, with a fresh new project, and got 67 build errors. Both Xcode and Firebase are crap. https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are targeting 9.2 then the frameworks changed to the following:

> libicucore.dylib to libicucore.tbd
>
> libc++.dylib to libc++.tbd

They are exactly the same so use them instead, you have to use them in order to get it working.

A comment by apple:

> For those who are curious, the .tbd files are new "text-based stub
>   libraries", that provide a much more compact version of the stub
>   libraries for use in the SDK, and help to significantly reduce its
>   download size.

Comment: THANK YOU!  That did it.

Comment: Firebase should update firebase.com/docs/ios/alternate-setup.html to specify the .tbd files for Xcode 7.2 users - would have saved me 2 hours ;)  Thx again!

Comment: Haha yes that is very annoying someone should make a pull request on github, maybe there is one already. But I am glad that it worked for you:)!