# Cannot call value of non-function type 'module<Firebase>'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase

i have a strange error when i was using firebase from google.

when i trying to init the Fire base setup the ref address for it using this code here

```
let BASE_URL = "YOUR_FIREBASE_URL"
var FIREBASE_REF = Firebase(url: BASE_URL)
```

, it shows an error:

```
Cannot call value of non-function type 'module<Firebase>'
```

my pod file looks like this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Mission Board' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase', '>=2.4.2'
end
```

Environment: 
Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1014) 
Firebase straight from the official site.
Swift language.

please anyone help ?

Comment: it seems you are using old way to install the firebase through cocoapod please follow this link  https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#prerequisites  i  also facing  the same issue .  and able to solved it

Answer (score 6):

My pod file looks like this :

```
platform :ios, ‘9.2’

    use_frameworks!

target 'firebaseWithChris' do

    pod 'Firebase'

    pod 'Firebase/Database'

end
```

Xcode:in viewController.swift file in viewDidLoad method

instead of

```
var rootRef = Firebase(url:"https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com")
```

try

```
var rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

This worked for me :]

Comment: This compiles for me too but where do you specify the url of the app?

Comment: @CristiBăluță It's in the GoogleService-Info.plist file

Answer (score 4):

I'm also new to Firebase and run in the same problem. It seems that  Firebase 3.2.0 and FirebaseDatabase 3.0.1. use different approach. The following worked for me:

```
let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL(BASE_URL)
var messageRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem.  You might be referring to some sample code for Firebase.com.  The API has been updated and is no longer referred to as "Firebase.com"  It's not clear what the new name is -- ?

Anyway, the link below guides you through updating your podfile to include:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
```

https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios

remember to run

```
pod update
```

and changing your code to call the new methods.  It's working for me with Xcode 7.2

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. So, this is what I did to resolve it. I uninstall Firebase Cocoapods. Then I installed Firebase manually.

I used this link.
https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/alternate-setup.html
and added the frameworks and dependencies that states on the this url.

Note: These libraries.
libicucore.dylib
libc++.dylib
Should be .tbd

The answer was given here.
[Xcode compile error with Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095808/xcode-compile-error-with-firebase)

After I manually installed Firebase the error went away. If anyone knows why I would love to know myself what caused this error.

Note: Google updated Firebase. So, maybe you look more into that.

Comment: do i just delete all the pod files that will be considered fully uninstall?

Comment: another question, to initiallize the firebase i need call FIRApp.configure() in appDelegate.swift but i found that has another error like this :         Use of unresolved identifier 'FIRApp' what cause that ?

Comment: @EberronBruce you are using old way to install the firebase through cocoa-pod  and i think your firebase version is 2.5.1 and current firebase version is 3.0.1 . use this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#add_the_sdk

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In order to resolve it, you have to modify your podfile. I wrote in my podfile those two lines (as it was asked by firebase in its intro video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joVi3thZOqc)

```
pod 'Firebase'

pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

i  also face  the same issue . i delete the ccocoa pod and follow this link to install the firebase through cocoapod . after that i am able to solve this problem

Step 1 :- you need  CocoaPods 1.0.0 or later

Step 2 :-  Create a Firebase project in the Firebase console,

Click Add Firebase to your iOS app and follow the setup steps. If you're importing an existing Google project, this may happen automatically and you can just download the config file.[click here](http://hhttps://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592)

Step 3 :- Add the SDK

pod 'Firebase'

now Initialize Firebase in your app

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#add_the_sdk

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is belonged to Google now. I had many updates. Please, take a look at: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios