# xcode error : Cannot call value of non-function type module Firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swift2

I try to use firebase from xcode and i have this error:

```
Cannot call value of non-function type module Firebase
```

(i did not have problem with Firebase import)

I try to setup again firebase manually but i have the same error!!

Do i have to uninstall cocoapods?

I use xcode 7.3.1(7d1014) and my pod file look like this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, ‘9.3’

target 'FIRST' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for FIRST
      pod ‘Firebase’, ‘>=2.5.1’

  target 'FIRSTTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

anyone help??

Comment: are you using the legacy console version of firebase or the firebase.google.com version?

Comment: I use tha firebase.google.com version!! Do i have to look for legacy console version?There is difference between this two version?

Comment: Nope is ok to use the google version.... i just wanted to know more information about the problem, you say the import Firebase works fine  and is recognised right?

Comment: yes i have no problem with import firebase! i try to write this two lines of code.                                                                                                              'let BASE_URL = "YOUR_FIREBASE_URL"
var FIREBASE_REF = Firebase(url: BASE_URL)' and i get the error!

Comment: ok those functions are only valid with the legacy version, if you are migrating the new way firebase works is here https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Comment: I wiil try with legacy version! Thank you Ymmanuel! I think your advise will help me!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install 'Firebase/database' using pod, as stated in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37437790/2301570