# I updated the cocoapods for Firebase and my app display error messages now

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some code lines that doesn't work anymore since I updated the Firebase with cocoapods.
For that examples, I give the error message :

```
   override init() {
        Firebase.defaultConfig().persistenceEnabled = true
      }
```

=> Cannot call value of non-function type 'module'<'Firebase>'
That other line:

```
  let rootRef = Firebase(url: "https://<mysite>.firebaseio.com/")
  var messageRef: Firebase!
```

=> Cannot call value of non-function type 'module'<'Firebase>''

```
messagesQuery.observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (snapshot: FDataSnapshot!) in
```

=> Use of undeclared type 'FDataSnapshot'

It seems that Firebase doesn't work anymore that way...

Comment: In your code you have imported Firebase?

Comment: I have just done that tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/122148/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat some month ago and I updated the cocoapods (with pod update). That the only things I have done.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631070/xcode-error-cannot-call-value-of-non-function-type-module-firebase

Comment: Interesting, I am goin' to investigate that way : https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios

Comment: Add all code in your question if you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it in the "new" Firebase.

First

```
override init() {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    FIRApp.configure()
}
```

Second

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
// To get a child use .child(childName)
```

Third

```
databaseRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
    snapshot in
    print(snapshot.value!)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

1) Look this tutorial. This guy explanes very well how to install firebase with cocoapods:

[Swift: Firebase 3 - Installing SDK using Cocoapods and Saving Users into Database](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=guFW9aj4EHM)

2) Otherwise you can follow this step by step guide on the official page if you want to try to put firebase again:

[Add Firebase to your iOS Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

**Add Firebase to your app**

It's time to add Firebase to your app. To do this you'll need a Firebase project and a Firebase configuration file for your app.

Create a *Firebase project* in the *Firebase console*, if you don't already have one. If you already have an existing Google project associated with your mobile app, click Import Google Project. Otherwise, click Create New Project.
Click Add Firebase to your iOS app and follow the setup steps. If you're importing an existing Google project, this may happen automatically and you can just download the config file.
When prompted, enter your app's bundle ID. It's important to enter the bundle ID your app is using; this can only be set when you add an app to your Firebase project.
At the end, you'll download a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file. You can download this file again at any time.
If you haven't done so already, copy this into your Xcode project root.
Note: If you have multiple build variants with different bundle IDs defined, each app must be added to your project in Firebase console.
Add the SDK

If you are setting up a new project, you need to install the SDK. You may have already completed this as part of creating a Firebase project.

We recommend using CocoaPods to install the libraries. You can install Cocoapods by following the installation instructions. If you'd rather not use CocoaPods, you can integrate the SDK frameworks directly by following the instructions below.

If you are planning to download and run one of the quickstart samples the Xcode project and Podfile are already present. If you would like to integrate the Firebase libraries into one of your own projects, you will need to install the pods for the libraries that you want to use.

If you don't have an Xcode project yet, create one now.
Create a Podfile if you don't have one:

```
$ cd your-project directory
$ pod init
```

Add the pods that you want to install. You can include a Pod in your Podfile like this:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

This will add the prerequisite libraries needed to get Firebase up and running in your iOS app, along with Firebase Analytics. A list of currently available pods and subspecs is provided below. These are linked in feature specific setup guides as well.

Install the pods and open the .xcworkspace file to see the project in Xcode.

```
$ pod install
$ open your-project.xcworkspace
```

Download a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file from Firebase console and include it in your app.

3) If you want to upgrade your existing app from Firebase.com:

[Upgrade your iOS app from Firebase.com](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13495284)

Comment: I've added some explanations and another link. I know that links can become invalid but now these links can help @Claudio.